# can i use a marco in multitab simulatensily in emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

i have done a marco for my job ,
my job is open mulitifile and use it
now , i use this marco one file to one file
i want to open multi-file in emeditor and used it simulatensily
how can i do it ?

my marco is like this

```
document.selection.SelectAll();
document.selection.EndOfdocument();
document.selection.Cut();   

strFileName= document.Name;
document.selection.EndOfdocument();
document.selection.Text="strFileName" +"\t" + strFileName + "\n";


document.selection.Find("(?<=\x22title\x22:\x22)(.*)(?=\x22,\x22pubdate\x22)",eeFindSelectAll |eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
str1 = document.selection.text;
document.selection.EndOfdocument();
document.selection.Delete();
//document.selection.text="hello,world\n"
document.selection.text="title:\t"+str1+"\n";


document.selection.Find("\x22page\x22:(\\d+),\x22from\x22:\x22vupload\x22,\x22part\x22:\x22(.*?)\x22",eeFindSelectAll |eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
document.selection.Copy();
document.selection.EndOfdocument();
document.selection.Paste();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Advanced Open** command in the **File** menu. To do this:

1. Open **EmEditor**.
2. Set the **Run a macro against each opened document** option.
3. Select or enter a macro path you want to run.
4. Click **Select Files to Open**, and select multiple files to open.
   [image: EmEditor - Advanced Open]